# Make the XmlMediaTypeFormatter use fallback characters when Encoding fails

Tags: c#, serialization, character-encoding, asp.net-web-api

So, I'm dealing with some pretty nasty legacy data, and I need pass some of it to a RESTful API.

I'm using WebApi Client (the nuget package), and I'm running into a problem:  Sometimes, one of my model objects contains a string that has an invalid XML character (like 0xf1).  There is no reason that these values should be in the data, so I really just want to filter them.

My problem:  When the XmlMediaTypeFormatter attempts to serialize my object graph, and it encounters one of these bad values, it throws. (expected)

What I would like to do is to make it silently fallback to a character that can be encoded.

I tried replacing the UTF8Encoding (see code below), but I still get the exception.  It seems that somewhere deep in the bowels of the DatacontractSerializer, they are using their own encoding object.

Anyone know of a way to get the XmlMediaFormatter to use fallback characters when an encoding error occurs?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var formatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter();
formatter.SupportedEncodings.Clear();

// the second param in the ctor is throwOnInvalidBytes = false
var newUtf8Encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false, false);
formatter.SupportedEncodings.Add(newUtf8Encoding);

var content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent(typeof(MyEntity), myInstance, formatter);

var stream = new MemoryStream();
content.CopyToAsync(stream).Wait(); // exception here, I hoped that fallback would occur
stream.Close();
```

- I know that our long term solution must be to fix the data.
- The only way to keep the data fixed is to fix the legacy code that is writing the bad values, and that is going to take significant time and effort.  We will do it, but I need a stop-gap.

Comment: which version of "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" package are you using? also could you share the repro code including the text you are trying to write?

Comment: What is the source of this special data? If this is some legacy system, you should be able to determine the source encoding of the string. It may not be UTF-8 but even if it is DBCS kind of stuff, trying to use the correct encoding based on the code page used in the legacy system and reading the string correctly will be the right stop-gap solution than ignoring those special characters, IMHO.

Comment: @KiranChalla I will get an SSCCE posted

Comment: @Badri It's coming from an nvarchar in SQL server.  source encoding is UTF-16.  Encoding problem was the first thing I thought as well, but but if it is an encoding problem, the corruption is occurring when the string is saved, and not on the read (in one case, the character flat shouldn't be there, it's a Gender field, the only valid values are "M", and "F").